# Having a problem with xorg.conf for a problematic monitor

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have two Westinghouse 26" L2610NW monitors that I run off of a GeForce GT X660. The graphics card has two DVI (one Digital, one analog), and an HDMI out. I run my primary display (Screen 0) off of the analog DVI port converted to VGA to plug into the monitor. The second monitor has to go in either the digital DVI or the HDMI port. Herein lies the problem:

The L2610NW monitors incorrectly report their refresh rates through EDID. This causes the monitor to show "Out of Range" whenever trying to run at 1920 x 1200 resolution, even though it is perfectly capable of it. I found a workaround for Windows listed here:
http://osardar.net/blog/?p=11
Using this solution, I am able to successfully run the second monitor in Windows at 1920 x 1200. It creates a new .inf file to use as a driver override. (Below this explanation I have posted the .inf contents)

Unfortunately I have not been able to get this to work in any form of Linux. I have tried using nvidia-settings and manually editing xorg.conf to force the refresh rate to 60hz (which is supposedly what is needed), but it doesn't work. nvidia-settings detects the second monitor but is unable to do anything with it.

Can someone please tell me exactly what settings are contained in this .inf file that I can make X recognize so I can use my two displays?!

monitor.inf contents:

---

```
; INF file generated by Monitor Asset Manager (2.60.0.972), 4/5/2013
; Copyright (c) EnTech Taiwan, 1995-2011.
; Internet: http://www.entechtaiwan.com

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Monitor
ClassGUID={4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Provider=%MFG%
DriverVer=4/5/2013, 1.0.0.0
;CatalogFile=YourSignedCatalogFile.cat

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=23

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%DISC%

[SourceDisksFiles]
;YourColorProfileFile.icm

[Manufacturer]
%VENDOR%=EDID_OVERRIDE,NTx86,NTamd64

[EDID_OVERRIDE.NTx86]
%PRODUCTID%=OVERRIDDEN-EDID.Install, MONITOR\WDE1478

[EDID_OVERRIDE.NTamd64]
%PRODUCTID%=OVERRIDDEN-EDID.Install.NTamd64, MONITOR\WDE1478

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID.Install.NTx86]
DelReg=DEL_CURRENT_REG
AddReg=OVERRIDDEN-EDID.AddReg, MODE1, DPMS
CopyFiles=OVERRIDDEN-EDID.CopyFiles

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID.Install.NTamd64]
DelReg=DEL_CURRENT_REG
AddReg=OVERRIDDEN-EDID.AddReg, MODE1, DPMS
CopyFiles=OVERRIDDEN-EDID.CopyFiles

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID.Install.NTx86.HW]
AddReg=OVERRIDDEN-EDID_AddReg

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID.Install.NTamd64.HW]
AddReg=OVERRIDDEN-EDID_AddReg

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID_AddReg]
;Base EDID
HKR,EDID_OVERRIDE,"0",0x01,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x5C,0x85,0x78,0x14,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0C,0x12,0x01,0x03,0x68,0x37,0x1F,0x78,0x2E,0xC5,0x85,0xA4,0x59,0x49,0x9A,0x24,0x12,0x50,0x54,0x3F,0xCF,0x00,0x81,0x00,0xD1,0x00,0x95,0x00,0xB3,0x00,0xA9,0x40,0xD1,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x28,0x3C,0x80,0xA0,0x70,0xB0,0x23,0x40,0x30,0x20,0x36,0x00,0x26,0x35,0x21,0x00,0x00,0x1A,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFD,0x00,0x38,0x4B,0x1E,0x50,0x15,0x00,0x0A,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x00,0x30,0x0A,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFC,0x00,0x4C,0x32,0x36,0x31,0x30,0x4E,0x57,0x0A,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x00,0xC0

[DEL_CURRENT_REG]
HKR,MODES
HKR,EDID_OVERRIDE
HKR,,MaxResolution
HKR,,PreferredMode
HKR,,DPMS
HKR,,ICMProfile

[DPMS]
HKR,,DPMS,,1

HKR,,PreferredMode,,"1920,1200,60"
[MODE1]
HKR,,MaxResolution,,"1920,1200,60"

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID.AddReg]
HKR,"MODES\1920,1200,60",Mode1,,"30.0-80.0,56.0-75.0,+,+"

[OVERRIDDEN-EDID.CopyFiles]
;YourColorProfileFile.icm for non-sRGB displays

[Strings]
MFG="EnTech Taiwan"
DISC="Monitor EDID Override Installation Disk"
PRODUCTID="Westinghouse L2610NW (WDE1478 EDID Override)"
VENDOR="Westinghouse"
```